# freeswitch use private address for rtp ( osx + docker + x-lite )

Tags: macos, docker, freeswitch

Environment

```
OSX: 10.12.2 (16C68)
Docker: Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)
freeswitch container: https://hub.docker.com/r/bettervoice/freeswitch-container/
```

Network

```
Docker container IP: 172.17.0.2
Docker host IP: 192.168.1.121
```

Docker setup

```
docker run -d \
        --name freeswitch \
        -p 5060:5060/tcp \
        -p 5060:5060/udp \
        -p 5066:5066/tcp \
        -p 5080:5080/tcp \
        -p 5080:5080/udp \
        -p 8021:8021/tcp \
        -p 7443:7443/tcp \
        -p 60535-60635:60535-60635/udp \
        -v /my/docker/freeswitch/conf:/usr/local/freeswitch/conf:rw \
        -v /my/docker/freeswitch/default_freeswitch:/etc/default/freeswitch \
        bettervoice/freeswitch-container:1.6.16
```

Only change the follow settings:

vars.xml

```
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="external_sip_ip=192.168.1.121"/>
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="external_rtp_ip=192.168.1.121"/>
```

sip_profiles/internal.xml:

```
<param name="ext-rtp-ip" value="$${external_rtp_ip}"/>
<param name="ext-sip-ip" value="$${external_sip_ip}"/>
```

sip_profiles/external.xml:

```
<param name="ext-rtp-ip" value="$${external_rtp_ip}"/>
<param name="ext-sip-ip" value="$${external_sip_ip}"/>
```

switch.conf.xml

```
<param name="rtp-start-port" value="60535"/>
<param name="rtp-end-port" value="60635"/>
```

default_freeswitch

```
# /etc/default/freeswitch
DAEMON_OPTS="-rp"
```

When I call X-Lite A (1000) -> X-Lite B(1001) , it use the private address 172.17.0.2 for rtp address. Actually I want these two X-Lite use 192.168.1.121 for rtp.

Could anyone give me some help ?